# casting string content to list

Tags: python, string, list

Let's assume I have list, and have turned it into a string (to use it as a dictionary key for example). Is there a way to get the list back from the string? This code snippet should illustrate what I want:

```
list_str = str([1,2,3])
my_list = some_operation(list_str)
```

such that the variable my_list contains the list [1,2,3]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just convert it to a tuple. `{tuple([1, 2, 3]): 'a'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ast.literal_eval(list_str)` but the real question is why did you convert it into a string in the first place? You could have converted it to a tuple (immutable and hashable) to use as a dict key

Answer (score -3):

It's not a good idea, but you can try:

```
# list_str holds your list in a string
vals = list_str[1:-1]
l = [int(x.strip()) for x in vals.split(",")]
```

Comment: if it's not a good idea, then why write an answer?

Comment: Thanks @Chris_Rands
Very helpful commentary.